Reading UTC timestamp in python pandas and converting it to European dates
I have an issue with a timestamp column, hoping you can provide me some support. I checked here few already posted questions, but somehow I couldn't find the right approach from them.
I have a pandas frame with multiple columns,among others a timestamp. This timestamp column contains utc dates. My goal is to extract only the dates, and write them in the european format dd.mm.yyyy because I need to save these dates into excel since I need to work there
import pandas as pd

Timestamp=[
"06.02.2024 00:43:31 UTC",
"06.02.2024 01:34:35 UTC",
"06.02.2024 02:21:41 UTC",
"06.02.2024 02:26:41 UTC",
"06.02.2024 03:19:52 UTC",
"06.02.2024 07:15:48 UTC",
"06.02.2024 08:22:46 UTC",
"06.02.2024 09:56:12 UTC",
"06.02.2024 12:00:43 UTC",
"06.02.2024 12:22:14 UTC",
"06.02.2024 12:23:21 UTC"]

df=pd.DataFrame(Timestamp)


df=df.rename(columns={0:"Timestamp"})

df["Timestamp"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Timestamp"],utc=True).dt.date
df["Timestamp"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Timestamp"])

print(df)
    Timestamp
0  2024-06-02
1  2024-06-02
2  2024-06-02
3  2024-06-02
4  2024-06-02
5  2024-06-02
6  2024-06-02
7  2024-06-02
8  2024-06-02
9  2024-06-02
10 2024-06-02


I need to have it in mm.dd.yyyy format
As said: i tried multiple ways but nothing really worked and I am sure that this ist not that complicated and I am just blind. Can you help me?

There's no such "European" format. Dates have no format, they're binary values. Formats only apply when parsing strings into dates or formatting dates as strings. Where do those strings come from? As far as I know only Russia and maybe Germany use dots. And only the US puts the month in front

save these dates into excel Excel has explicit date support so no, you don't need to format anything. You'll cause problems if you replace dates with localized strings. to_excel will save dates (the Python or Pandas types, not the strings) as proper Excel dates. To truncate time use .dt.date

Where does the data come from? If it comes from a database it's probably stored as an actual date, not strings. In that case read_sql will load the values as proper dates that don't need parsing. read_csv also allows specifying a format, removing the need to parse after loading

Try This
pd.to_datetime(df["Timestamp"], utc=True).dt.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')

help

All you have to do is just call to_excel. No conversion is necessary.
Dates are binary values, they have no format. Excel dates are stored as binary values as well, so no formats are involved either. More specifically, dates are stored as floating point numbers internally and displayed as dates when the correct style is applied. to_excel will save Date values properly.
There's no "European" format either. As far as I know only Russia and Germany use dots. Every country has its own format. Only the US puts the month at the front though.
All that's needed to save these dates to Excel is to call to_excel:
df.to_excel(path_to_file)

